# How to test SSO integration?

Tags: automated-testing, qa-developer, security-testing

I am doing QA for a website, and they have recently added SSO integration for their website.

1. How can I manually test that this SSO integration is working fine.
2. Also I need to automate the testing of SSO integration . How can i do that?

Comment: For clarification, is the SSO a 3rd party integration? Or is the SSO functionality created by the same development team as the website? Is two factor authentication (2FA) a feature in use by SSO? Testing approach would be different depending on how SSO is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSO can be tested using API Testing via Postman or SOAP or what ever API tools you are using. Every page of the website will have some or the other endpoints. 
If SSO is implemented then all the endpoints will require a specific one time token.

To generate the token first execute the Login API with username and password and generate the Auth Token. This Auth Token should then be used as "Auth-Token" in the Header or in the Body of request of the API.

If SSO has been implemented and then if you hit those endpoints or API's separately without passing the Auth-Token in the header then those endpoints will fail else it will pass.

For Automating the SSO use Rest Assured.